# Redux action argument dispatch difference

Tags: reactjs, redux

My dispatch and actions are initially like this, and console.log(action.index) gives undefined.

```
onClick={() => this.props.actions.setResultMenu({x})}


export const setResultMenu = ({index}) => ({
    type: SET_RESULT_MENU,
    index
});
```

However, when I changed {x} to x, everything works

```
onClick={() => this.props.actions.setResultMenu(x)}


export const setResultMenu = (index) => ({
    type: SET_RESULT_MENU,
    index
});
```

May I know the reason why?

Comment: Well, what were you thinking `{x}` would do in that context?

Comment: It will create an object with key x?

Comment: Yes! Still need this question?

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood destructuring and object initializer shorthand syntax. Take a look what happens in each of your cases.

Let's have two functions, one basic, and one with curly braces around parameter (thats destructuring):

```
function takeArg(arg) {
    return arg;
}

function takeArgDestr({field}) {
    return field;
}
```

And object `obj`:

```
const obj = {
    field: 'some field',
    anotherField: 'another field'
}
```

Here is basic case - pass object, print it as is:

```
takeArg(obj);
// {
//     field: "some field",
//     anotherField: "another field"
// }
```

When we pass obj with curly braces, object like `{obj: obj}` will be created and passed to function (this is object initializer shorthand):

```
takeArg({obj})
// {
//    obj: {
//        field: "some field",
//        anotherField: "another field"
//    }
// }
```

See? We have object with nested `obj` printed.

Next, lets use function with destructuring, `takeArgDestr`.

Function has curly braces around parameter, so it will destructure passed argument. Take obj, get `field` and print its value:

```
takeArgDestr(obj)
// "some field"
```

And here is your `undefined` case. We pass object with curly braces, so creating nested object `{obj: obj}`, and function tries to get `field` from that object. And we don't have this field there, so got `undefined`.

```
takeArgDestr({obj})
// undefined
```

You can play with all this cases in this plunk:
http://www.webpackbin.com/VyIZ2VsRW

**Destructuring:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
For your case, see section "Pulling fields from objects passed as function parameter".

**Object initialize shorthand:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer